# How to plot a grouped geom_bar plot having a dataframe?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have a dataframe like this one:

[image]

and want to plot in R something like this:

[image]

But for some reason I am really struggling with the grouped geom_bar code...
Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `barplot` from `base R`

```
barplot(t(df1), beside = TRUE, col = c("blue", "orange", "grey", 
       "yellow", "lightblue" ))
```

-output

[image]

---

Or if we need a `ggplot/plotly`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(plotly)
library(tibble)
p <- df1 %>% 
   rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -rn) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = rn, y = value, fill = name)) +
        geom_col(position = 'dodge') + 
     theme_bw()
ggplotly(p)
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(65, 9, 7, 70, 9), B = c(23, 4, 5, 53, 2), 
    C = c(42, 5, 2, 17, 7), D = c(51, 7, 5, 57, 5), E = c(14, 
    2, 2, 13, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("AAA", 
"BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Really appreciated

Comment: Also, I know that for this case it does not make sense but imagine that I wanted to add a secondary axis for the "column E". Would it be difficult to implement it?

Comment: @JoãoMachado It is not that difficult, but it is very much discouraged by the authors of the package

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using the `tidyverse` package that contains `ggplot2` and `tidyr` packages. Additionally, this answer includes plotting the numbers as text on top of the bars.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  # Convert rownames to a new column named rowname
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  # Put data into long format
  pivot_longer(cols = -rowname,
               names_to = "letter") %>%
  # Build plot
  ggplot(aes(x = rowname, y = value, fill = letter)) +
  # Draw column plot and set position = "dodge" so every column
  # starts from 0 value
  geom_col(position = "dodge", width = 0.9) +
  # Add text, sum 2 to value so the label is plotted on top of the column
  geom_text(aes(y = value+2, label = value), 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  # Add bw theme or any other
  theme_bw()
```

[image: column plot]

Comment: Thank you for your help! Really appreciated Adding the numbers is a nice touch

Comment: Also, I know that for this case it does not make sense but imagine that I wanted to add a secondary axis for the "column E". Would it be difficult to implement it?

Comment: No, that's easily done using `scale_y_continuous(...,sec.axis)`.

Comment: Hi @Jonathan, sorry to bother you again but when using this code I get this error
`Error: Can't combine <character> and <integer>`. DO you have any tip? It seems that my AAA values are characters and my letter values are integers and I cannot do the long format